# Does SQL check each And condition if first condition fails?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan, query-performance

For a query of below kind does sql process data for each `And` condition if first `And` condition fails? If Emp_ID is not 12 for a row then does it check condition of Emp_Name?
So how SQL process this kind of queries?

```
SELECT [Emp_ID],[Emp_Name],[Emp_Sal] FROM [gyh].[dbo].[Employee_Demo] where Emp_ID='12' And Emp_Name like '%ab%'
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're talking about is [Short Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Unlike in CASE statements (except certain scenarios using variables and aggregate functions), where the order is important, [you have little control over the order in which the `WHERE` clause in SQL Server is evaluated](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/02/22/sql-server-short-circuit.aspx) (except with some grouping paratheses). So, even if it does short-circuit, SQL Server may choose to evaluate the second clause first, especially if that is referenced as the first column in the index it chooses to use for the query.

SQL Server **will** still attempt to parse the entire query to make sure it is logically correct, regardless of whether the first `AND` condition fails.

For example, if I use the AdventureWorks database and look for a City that I know doesn't exist:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO

-- obviously don't use SELECT * in production
SELECT 
   * 
FROM Person.Address AS a
WHERE City = 'Bournemouth' AND 1/0 = 1
```

Even though `City = 'Bournemouth'` will always be `FALSE`, I still get the error:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Comment: FYI, `CASE` will sometimes not short circuit as well, with edge-case scenarios involving local variables and aggregate functions.

Comment: @JNK did not know that! Edited answer. Thanks